Fecha relativa en etiqueta time con moment.js o day.js
Estoy trabajando con moment para mostrar una fecha relativa, por ejemplo: "hece 1 hora" usando la etiqueta time y su atributos datetime de HTML.
No tengo alternativa con day.js por eso intento con moment.js pero aún así no puedo lograr mostrar aún con la etiqueta time.
Porque quiero mostrar en varias tarjetas : "hace 1 hora".
Pero hay si hay forma de hacer con moment.js o con day.js, agradecería mucho


const hoy = document.getElementById("hoy");
const es = document.querySelector("html").getAttribute("lang");

moment.locale(es);
let nuevo = moment();

const demo = nuevo.startOf('2024-11-10').format('ll');
  
hoy.innerHTML = demo;
<h1 id="hoy"></h1>
<time datetime="2024-11-10">No se vé aquí "hace..."</time>

<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js"></script>




Hola Narciso, ¿que queres decir con "No tengo alternativa con day.js"?

@Marcos, es que hace un tiempo trabaje con moment y olvide como mostrar la fecha del atributo time en el mismo time. Ahora quise implementar esa función con Day.js y me es imposible por no conocer el uso de Day. Pero quisiera actualizarme a Day.js

Debes usar la función fromNow() (documentación oficial) que devuelve el tiempo pasado o por pasar en referencia al momento indicado. Si la fecha está en el futuro, será el tiempo que queda hasta esa fecha; y si la fecha está en el pasado, será el tiempo transcurrido hasta ahora.
Aquí lo puedes ver en funcionamiento con el código de arriba:


const hoy = document.getElementById("hoy");
const es = document.querySelector("html").getAttribute("lang");

moment.locale(es);
let nuevo = moment('2024-11-10');

const demo = nuevo.format('ll');
hoy.innerHTML = demo;

document.querySelector("time").innerHTML = nuevo.fromNow();
<html lang="es">
  <h1 id="hoy"></h1>
  <time datetime="2024-11-10">No se vé aquí "hace..."</time>

  <script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
</html>




Gracias  resolvió mi problema

En base a tu comentario:

[...] Ahora quise implementar esa función con Day.js y me es imposible por no conocer el uso de Day. Pero quisiera actualizarme a Day.js

La librería Day.js al igual que moment.js posee:

Tiempo desde ahora


Devuelve la cadena de tiempo relativo a partir de ahora.
Esto requiere el RelativeTime plugin para trabajar.


LocalizedFormat


LocalizedFormat extiende la API dayjs().format para proporcionar opciones de formato localizado.


i18n


Day.js tiene un gran apoyo para la internacionalización.
Pero ninguno de ellos será incluido en tu construcción a menos que lo utilices.
Puedes cargar múltiples localizaciones y cambiar entre ellas fácilmente.
Lista de idiomas soportados

Ejemplo:


// Locale
dayjs.locale('es'); // locale

// Plugins
dayjs.extend(window.dayjs_plugin_relativeTime);
dayjs.extend(window.dayjs_plugin_localizedFormat);

//
const hoy = document.getElementById("hoy");
let nuevo = dayjs('2024-11-10');
const demo = nuevo.format('ll');
hoy.innerHTML = demo;

document.querySelector("time").innerHTML = nuevo.fromNow();
<html lang="es">
  <h1 id="hoy"></h1>
  <time datetime="2024-11-10">No se vé aquí "hace..."</time>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/dayjs.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/locale/es.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/plugin/relativeTime.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/plugin/localizedFormat.js"></script>
</html>




Gracias. Voy a trabajar en ello aunque necesita mucho plugins.

@NarcisoAifuz, si, pero fijate que moment-with-locales.js pesa 110k. en cambio day.js más todos los plugins, aprox. 8k.
